# How to pass in a brace-enclosed initializer list to a function?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, list-initialization, range-based-loop

I want to write a function that can be used with an argument that otherwise could directly occur in a range-based loop:

```
template <typename Iterable>
void sayIt(const Iterable& stuff) {
    for (const auto& e : stuff) {
        cout << e << endl;
    }
}
```

This works fine with stl containers and other types, but not with a brace-enclosed initializer:

```
std::vector<std::string> baz(2, "sorry");
sayIt(baz);              // okay
sayIt({"foo", "bar"});   // not okay
```

Is there a way to make the function work with both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Braced-init-list has no type and cause [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts) failing.

> **Non-deduced contexts**
>
> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose P do not participate in template argument deduction, but instead use the template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> 6. The parameter P, whose A is a braced-init-list, but P is not [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), a reference to one (possibly cv-qualified), or a reference to an array:

You can specify the template argument as `std::initializer_list` explicitly to bypass the deduction,

```
sayIt<std::initializer_list<std::string>>({"foo", "bar"});
```

Or add another overload taking `std::initializer_list`.

```
template <typename T>
void sayIt(std::initializer_list<T> stuff) {
    sayIt<decltype(stuff)>(stuff);
}
```

Comment: If I was to write `auto init = { "foo", "bar" };` and then `sayIt(init);` it will work. The compiler is deducing `init` as type `std::initializer_list<const char*>`. But doesn't it doesn't do the same with `{ "foo", "bar" }`. Why?

Comment: @jignatius Because there's special rule for [auto type deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Other_contexts). With copy-list-initalization, `init` will be deduced as `std::initializer_list`.