# why c++ emplace_back can't decltype c arrays?

Tags: c++

As the code below shown, emplace_back with c array only works if I explicitly state the type, why's that?

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(const float (&t)[2])
    {
    }
};
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    std::vector<Foo> foos;
    Foo foo({0.f, 0.f}); // ok
    foos.emplace_back({0.f,0.f}); // error
    foos.emplace_back<const float (&)[2]>({0.f, 0.f}); // ok
}
```

Comment: `emplace_back` has to figure out what the type of  `{0.f,0.f}` is. "Anything convertible to Foo" isn't enough, as that would require a two-step deduction. C++ just doesn't do that.

Comment: @BoP I would have said that ```emplace_back``` is looking for a constructor from std::initializer_list and can't find one but [adding one](https://godbolt.org/z/n6Tsce6sd) does not improve. I'm also wondering why.

Comment: IIRC, template argument deduction does not work for _brace-init-lists_. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/443hbfYqv. Relevant questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17496268/580083 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/63407026/580083.